# Unity Error CS1519 in Simple Activator Menu

Tags: unity-game-engine

New to Unity. Had a problem with GUI, had to change it to UI. GUIText has been changed to Text to resolve previous error message:

[link here to photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQW1M.png)

Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(10,5): error CS1519: Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Answer (score 0):

You already have a '{' on line 9, but you also have one on line 10. Remove the bracket from line 10.

Also, for future reference, post your code using the code tags and not as an image.

Comment: More error messages, says "the type or namespace name "monobehaviour" could not be found, also "gameobject" cannot be found

Comment: @JackTyrrell you need to add `using UnityEngine;` at the beginning of the file (on line 3). It will allow you to use Unity-specific classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however new error message: Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(36,12): error CS1513: } expected (I've added more tags but nothing's working)

Comment: Could you post the whole script somewhere, for example Hastebin?

Comment: Turns out I didn't need it so I just deleted the script. Thanks for the help though, much appreciated.